# How to upload files to HTML5 Web App from Google Drive or Onedrive?

Tags: android, ios, html, google-drive-api, onedrive

I am designing an web application that will allow applying for the jobs we post in our career page. The application will use responsive design and should make it easy for mobile users (iOS and Android initially) to upload their resumes. I read something about uploading files to Google Drive or MS Onedrive using their corresponding APIs. However, I am trying to do the opposite; browse files, select a resume, perhaps download it locally, and finally upload it to my web application.

Do you know if this is possible? If so, what would be your recommendation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First you can ask the user to authorize to use their Google Drive Data using OAuth2.0. The below two reference links from the Google Drive API will be useful 
1.Get the list of filenames using the filelist option in the api and fetch the filename from the list https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

2. Download the file directly to your server using the Downloads feature of the API
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

I hope this gives you enough direction to proceed further.